php container unable to reach mysql within teamcity pipeline
I recently tried to migrate my pipelines to teamcity for a project but ran into issues with my pipelines within teamcity not being able to connect to my mysql container.
It's a hard requirement to use mysql and cannot change this to sqlite since we create custom mysql functions that also need to be tested.
I created a brand new laravel project without any modifications to test out the new pipeline. The only changes to a default laravel 11 app is the docker-compose.yml file.
Here is my docker-compose.yml
services:
  php:
    hostname: teamcity-php-fpm
    container_name: teamcity-php-fpm
    build:
      context: docker/php
    ports:
      - 5173:5173
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www:cached
    networks:
      - teamcity-app
  db:
    networks:
      - teamcity-app
    image: mysql:8.3
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
      - teamcity-mysql:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./docker/logs:/var/log/mysql
      - ./docker/db/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/my.cnf
      - ./docker/db/sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}

  nginx:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www
      - ./docker/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./docker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    depends_on:
      - php
    networks:
      - teamcity-app
volumes:
    teamcity-mysql:
        driver: local
networks:
  teamcity-app:
    driver: bridge

Locally my build is successful and everything is working, however when I try to run the same within teamcity it's unable to connect to the database.
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (Connection: mysql, SQL: select table_name as `name`, (data_length + index_length) as `size`, table_comment as `comment`, engine as `engine`, table_collation as `collation` from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'laravel' and table_type in ('BASE TABLE', 'SYSTEM VERSIONED') order by table_name)

Steps within teamcity:

Copy .env.teamcity .env
build docker-compose.yml file
run docker exec teamcity-php-fpm php artisan migrate << This is failing

I just can't seem to figure out why this is failing within teamcity but not locally?

It is not clear from the question where the code that attempts to connect to mysql runs and what the connecrion parameters are. It is also inclear if you made sure if nysql is up and running before you try to connect ro it.

@Shadow The dockerc-compose is responsible for setting the credentials to the database. As the DB_HOST I have the name of the container db.
I did attempt to run docker ps which shows the database is running.

db_host parameter is not in your question, nor are any other connection parameters. You run docker ps after everything starts working, not when your app starts to run.

@Shadow I managed to find the issue anyway. The issue was that the pipeline attempted to run the tests before the mysql server was finished starting up.

I managed to find the issue, it was due to the mysql server not being done booting up while the build was already attempting to run the unit tests.
My changes in the docker-compose.yml
  services:
   mysql:
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-h", "localhost" ]
      interval: 15s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 10
   php-fpm:
      depends_on:
        mysql:
          condition: service_healthy

What helped me was running docker logs mysql inbetween build steps to see if there was any issue with the database. There I realized it simply wasn't done booting up and wouldn't accept connections yet.
